# Google Maps API - How to only plot the first and last marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using `Geolocation` and the Google Maps API to create a tracking app. At the moment it tracks the users position using the `watchPosition()` function. It currently plots a new blue icon everytime it receives a new longitude and latitude position. However I just want it to plot the start position (which it already is, using the red marker.) and then for it to only show the blue icon when it receives the latest coordinates, instead of putting a blue icon on the map every time it receives a new position.

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwzVed)

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="dvContent">

</div>

<div id="map_canvas">
    Hello
</div>
<!-- <input type="text" name="'adr" id="address" value="-41.2889, 174.7772" />
<input type="button" value="Start Watching" id="start">
<input type="button" value="Stop Watching" id="stop">
<input type="button" value="Delete Markers" id="delete"> -->


<script type="text/javascript">

    var watchID = null;
    var geo;
    var map;
    var startMarker = []; // Red Icon
    var endMarker = []; // Blue Icon
    var geo_options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, 
        maximumAge        : 10000000, 
        timeout           : 20000
    };
    var pathLineArray = new Array();
    var mypath;
    var geocoder;
    var mapMarkerRevCode;

    console.log(startMarker);



$(document).ready(function(){

    function getGeoLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            return navigator.geolocation;
        } else {
            return "undefined";
        }
    }

    function startWatching(){
        watchID = geo.watchPosition(show_coords, geo_error, geo_options);
        // watchID = geo.getCurrentPosition(show_coords, geo_error, geo_options);
    }

    function stopWatching(){
        if (watchID!=null) {
            geo.clearWatch(watchID);
        }
    }

    $('#start').click(startWatching);

    $('#stop').click(stopWatching);

    if(geo = getGeoLocation()){
        startWatching();
    } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported');
    }
});

function show_coords(position){

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

    if (map) {

        // Makes it so that it doesnt have to reload the map everytime, it just pans to the new position
        map.panTo(latlng);

    } else {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var mypath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathLineArray,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map

        });

        startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,

        });

    }
    // Push lat and long coords to this array
    pathLineArray.push(latlng);

    if (mypath) {
        mypath.setPath(pathLineArray);

    } else {
        mypath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathLineArray,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            map: map,

        });
    }

    endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
    });


}


function geo_error(error){
    switch(error.code){
        case error.TIMEOUT:
        alert("geolocation timeout");
        break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        alert("Gelocation position unavailable");
        break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        alert("Permission denied");
        break;
        default:
        alert('Unknown error');
    }
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by latest position? When the user moves to a new location isn't going to be the latest position as you get the new coordinate ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I will explain better. There is an array that is storing every new lat and long coords that gets received. For example [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]. At the moment it is plotting a blue icon for every one of these coords received. But I only want the last one plotted on the map using the blue icon out of that array. E.g in this example "g". Hope that helps?

Comment: Yes that helps. If I understood you correctly, after recieving coordinates a,b,c,d,e,f,g,you are seeing 7 blue markers in the view. isn't it ? If yes, you can check with https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove to remove markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the end marker if it already exists rather than making a new one each time.

```
if (endMarker && endMarker.setPosition) {
  endMarker.setPosition(latlng);
} else {
  endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dazxpknx/)